# selecting a char in jquery

Tags: jquery

I got a question,

```
<a id="shoppingLink1" href="?page=bestellen&amp;action=add&amp;id=2">
  <img src="images/shoppingcartButton.png" class="shoppingButton"  alt="shoppingcartButton" title="shoppingcartButton"/>
</a><br/>
```

in jquery, when i click on the shoppingButton i would like to select the last character from the id "shoppingLink". the "1" .

These are dynamicly added thou so if it comes to 10 it should automaticly select the last 2 characters. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Can you show in more detail what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.shoppingButton').click(function () {
    var id = parseInt($(this).parent('a[id^=shoppingLink]').attr('id').match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);

    // Do stuff.

    return false;
});​
```

This uses RegExp to match all digits at the end of `$(this).parent('a[id^=shoppingLink]').attr('id')` (i.e. the `.shoppingButton`'s parent `a`'s `id` attribute where the `id` begins with `"shoppingLink"`).  It then parses these digits into a number with `parseInt`.

Comment: this looks to be exactyl what i'm looking for, however the regexp gives an error. firebug says: $(this).parent("a").attr("id").match(/\d+$/) is null

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call it `shopping-link-1` or something similar, and put the `shoppingButton` class on the `a` tag instead of `img`? That way you can use the `split` method to get the numeric ID. Here's some example jQuery to use:

```
$('a.shoppingButton').click(function() {
    var link_id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-')[2]);
    // do your thing with link_id here
});
```

That way, when you split by the `'-'` character, it's guaranteed to just return the number no matter how many digits it has. But if you absolutely need to keep the current markup, use a regular expression:

```
$('img.shoppingButton').click(function() {
    var  link_id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').match(/(\d+)$/)[1]);
    // do your thing with link_id here
});
```

That way it will respond to clicks on the image, and still pull the ID from the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at it the other way round: you know to expect the string 'shoppingLink' so strip that off first then parse the number:

```
$('a.shoppingButton').click(function() {
    var theID = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('shoppingButton', ''));
    theID = isNaN(theID) ? 0 : theID;
    // actions here
});​
```